# Can android reference a library project with a variable within Eclipse?

Tags: android, ant

Is it possible to use a variable to reference a library project for use within Eclipse?

Ideally what I want is to define a variable for the location of a library project that allows team members (and our build server) to use different values:

```
android.library.reference.1=${some_library}
```

The problem is that the Eclipse build process doesn't seem to recognise (and substitute) the variable (even if the variable is in the same file).

In my understanding, the project.properties file should be checked in to version control, but if variable substitution isn't supported, anyone using Eclipse will have to have the same folder structure as defined in the checked in file.

Is this approach possible with Eclipse or should I be using a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

In the project.properties file i'm using the below to use the library REST_CLIENT in the previous level of the project :

```
  android.library=true
  android.library.reference.1=../REST_CLIENT
```

maybe you should add this line to your definition 
android.library=true